# hpacucli - format disk and create logical drive

Tags: debian, fdisk

I just added to the server new disk, which can't be seen by `fdisk -l`. But I can see it as physical drive via `hpacucli` as  `physicaldrive 1I:1:1 (port 1I:box 1:bay 1, SAS, 146 GB, OK)`

But on that disk are old data which I want to erase. Also create partition on that disk sda1 with size of 20GB. Is that possible with `hpacucli` since I dont see that disk with `fdisk`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bad. Had to create raid, which created logical volume which I can see with fdisk.